# Popup Pictures in Python Snake Game

Tags: python, pygame

So I made the typical beginner Python snake game, but I want to modify it so that Jpeg images pop up inside the snake game whenever the player reaches a certain milestone in points. For example, if the player reaches 5 points, picture 1 pops up and then picture 2 appears when the player scores 10 points.

Tutorial I followed to make the game is linked below:
https://www.edureka.co/blog/snake-game-with-pygame/

Comment: What is your question about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a variable that stores the score. use an if statement to check if the score has been reached. Try adding this to the main loop:

```py
if score == 5:
    screen.blit(picture1, position)
elif score == 10:
    screen.blit(picture2, position)
```

Replace `position` with the x and y coordinates you want the image to be at.

Comment: ooooh that makes so much sense, thanks.. But if the pic were in my PC folder (like downloads or a desktop folder), how exactly would i get my code to use the image?

Comment: a simple way is to move the images into the same folder as the program. Then you can use `pygame.image.load("image1.png")` to load the image. The image doesn't have to be a .png though.